# Reference subquery several times

Tags: sql, sqlite

Simplified version of the statement I try to run (`a`, `b`, and `m` are tables with only one column containing integers):

```
SELECT * FROM m WHERE 
    c1 IN (SELECT * FROM a) OR
    c1 IN (SELECT * FROM b)
    AND (NOT c1 IN (SELECT * FROM a) 
         OR  c1 IN (SELECT * FROM b));
```

I know this could be done more easily, but I have to keep this structure (i.e. cannot JOIN for instance). How could I avoid repeating the subqueries after the AND NOT, since they will return the same set as the previous ones?

Comment: Doesn't sqlite optimize this away?

Comment: Not sure at all. That would be interesting to know though.

Comment: Even if it did, the question would remain - beyond optimization, you usually do not want to have duplicate code bits that would make your query complex to maintain.

Comment: I need to do that in one statement. Moreover views are not indexed in SQLite.